# URL Shortener & Site Redirection on same domain

Tags: nginx, debian, rewrite

i have one domain(http://sdm.fm), And I would like it to work as a redirect to http://somdomato.com.

But at the same time I would like it to work as a URL shortener. 
Using phURL.

Like: sdm.fm/hd562fi

It's possible?

I have tried this:

```
    location ^/links/([^\.]+)$ {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite /links$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
            #rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) /wp$1 last;
            #rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ /wp$1 last;
        }
    }

    location ^([^\.]+)$ {
            rewrite "^(.*)$" /links/redirect.php?alias=$1 last;
    }
```

But not working.

I'm using Nginx + ISPConfig + PHP5-FPM on Debian Wheezy 64 bits.

Thanks.

### EDIT 1

```
    #location ~ ^/?$ {
    location = / {
        return 301 http://somdomato.com;
    }

    location ^/links/([^\.]+)$ {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite /links$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
            #rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) /wp$1 last;
            #rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ /wp$1 last;
        }
    }

    location ^([^\.]+)$ {
            rewrite "^(.*)$" /links/redirect.php?alias=$1 last;
    }
```

Almost, redirect is OK, but phURL is not working.
phURL is in: sdm.fm/links

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. What's the problem?

Comment: So you need `sdm.fm` redirect to main site and `sdm.fm/anything` act as url shortener?

Comment: Exactly alexeyten!

Comment: But i want short URL like: sdm.fm/short-URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd write something like this:

```
# Here sdm.fm goes
location = / {
    return 301 http://somdomato.com;
}

# Here sdm.fm/anything
location / {
    rewrite "^(.+)$" /links/redirect.php?alias=$1 last;
}

location = /links/redirect.php {
    internal;
    ... fastcgi rules to get to your php-fpm ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea but adding the following location should do the job:

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://somdomato.com;
}
```

Comment: Please, change it to `location = / { ... }`

Comment: Ok, but this way, phURL on sdm.fm/links won't work, right?

Comment: @alexeyten You are right this way is more straight forward.

Comment: @LucasSaliésBrum `sdm.fm/links` is short url by your definition. Isn't it?

Comment: @LucasSaliésBrum the location will match if and only if there is no URL path.

Comment: @alexeyten i'm trying to convert this rules to /links/ folder: https://code.google.com/p/phurl/issues/detail?id=78